# Duplicating a session in FileZilla

Tags: windows-7, filezilla

Is there any way to duplicate a session in [FileZilla FTP client](https://filezilla-project.org/), i.e. creating a new tab that automatically connected to the same server as the current tab?

E.g. [SuperPuTTY](https://code.google.com/p/superputty/):

[image]

I tried to right click on current tab in FileZilla but I don't see any option:

[image]

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and the latest version of FileZilla.

Edit: I am already using the site manager and I am aware of the option "Copy current connection to Site Manager" (which creates a new entry in the site manager, which I don't want).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in Filezilla, however you should be able to save your connection details in the connection manager.

You can then re-select your connection from the connection manager drop down list (top left of screen), you will get a prompt to either "Establish connection in a new tab" or "Abort previous connection and connect in current tab".

Selecting the first of these two options will open an additional tab with the same details to the same server, however it will load with whatever default home directory and local directory you specified.  If you set these paths to a commonly used folder, this will give you as close as you can currently get with defautl behaviour in FileZilla.

Comment: Thanks, yes I am already using the connection manager but I was looking for a faster way to create a new tab with the same connection parameters.